# Not possible to sign players based in England on free transfer

Tags: football-manager-2017

Since the 2020/2021 season it does no more seem possible to sign players based in England on a free transfer. I thought that maybe there was something special with 2020/2021, but now I am one months from expiring contracts at the end of the 2021/2022 season and it is still the same:

I am playing as a club based in England.

Below is an example of where the *Approach To Sign* option used to be available:

[image: Cannot sign on free transfer]

Also, it seems that after the contract have expired, if the player chooses to stay at the club on a weekly based contract, I still cannot sign the player.

Is it supposed to work this way? The game gave me news about England leaving the EU, and the only thing I can think of is that this has something to do with it. On the other hand, I can still sign EU players not based in England on free transfer.

I have tried google with no luck. Does anybody know the reason for this behaviour? Is it a bug?

Comment: http://arstechnica.com/gaming/2016/11/football-manager-2017-review/

Comment: @badp Really interesting reading (should have included "brexit" in my google search...). I added to my question that I still can sign other EU players on free transfers. I did not find anything about that in the article. That I __would__ have understood. But why can I not sign english players?

Comment: yeah, I didn't post an answer because I don't play this game and I don't have the full picture :) maybe it's like US work permits where the permit binds the employee to their current employer but I'm really speculating here

Comment: Just noticed that now (the end of the 23/24 season) I am able to sign players again. If there was a message in my inbox about this, I missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is apparently a feature of the game, one of the possible Brexit effects(quoting Ben Kenney from Sports Interactive):

> A possible brexit scenario will see UK players protected from being signed on pre-contracts or bosmans once the England/UK has left the EU. It may still be possible to sign players from outside the EU on pre-contracts.

[Forum thread link](https://community.sigames.com/topic/392434-bosman-ruling-stops/)